# Javascript functions not being called in JSPs

Tags: java, javascript, function, jsp

SOLVED: Stray `}` within the Javascript. Eclipse IDE doesn't check these when in a JSP.

I'm having trouble getting my Javascript functions to be called in my JSP. I have commented above which functions are working and not working. My goal is to have my dropdown boxes to be preselected based on a passed parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //this alert not working
    alert('alert1');

function preloadDropdownBoxes() {
    //preload function alert not calling
    alert('preload function called');
    //mapping vars to java variables
    var sYear = '<%=sYear%>';
    var collectionPeriod = '<%=collectionPeriod%>';
    var submission = '<%=submission%>';
    var availDate = '<%=availDate%>';
    var openDate = '<%=openDate%>';
    var closeDate = '<%=closeDate%>';
    //these are time generated values based on calendar instance
    var pastTwoYear = '<%=pastTwoYear%>';
    var pastYear = '<%=pastYear%>';
    var currentYear = '<%=currentYear%>';
    var futureYear = '<%=futureYear%>';
    //change selectedIndex values if dropdown in JSP has "pastTwoYear"
    if (sYear == pastTwoYear) {
        document.getElementById('pastTwoYear').selectedIndex = 0;
    } else if (sYear == pastYear) {
        document.getElementById('past').selectedIndex = 0;
        alert(sYear + '0');
    } else if (sYear == currentYear) {
        document.getElementById('current').selectedIndex = 1;
        alert(sYear + '1');
    } else if (sYear == futureYear) {
        document.getElementById('future').selectedIndex = 2;
        alert(sYear + '2');
    } else if(sYear == futureTwoYear) {
        document.getElementById('futureTwoYear').selectedIndex = 3;
        alert(sYear + '3');
    }
} //end preLoadDropdownBoxes()
</script>
```

I then have code for my dropdown boxes. Here is a snippet:

```
<select name="sYear1" id="sYear1" onchange="javascript:PreselectMyItem();">
                        <option value="past"><%=cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)-2%>-<%=cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)-1%></option>
                        <option value="current"><%=cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)-1%>-<%=cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)%></option>
                        <option value="future"><%=cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)%>-<%=cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)+1%></option>
                    </select>
```

Now, finally, I have another script on the bottom. I plan on putting my `preloadDropdownBoxes();` function at the end. I tried used `$(document).ready` but it wasn't working. Code is as follows:

```
    <script>
//     these two alert calls work
alert('footer');
alert('footer next');
//     these functions aren't being called
window.preloadDropdownBoxes();
document.getElementById('future').selectedIndex = 2;
window.alert('document ready on bottom');

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I've made my Test button as follows `<input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:alert('test');"/>` and this alert does work. There seems to be something wrong with the document not being able to register the functions in my script up top because I tried
        function test() {
        alert('hello');
    }
But the above snippet function isn't called when the button is: `<input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:test();"/>`

Comment: Is any error reported in the browser console?

Comment: Does it work with mock data?

Comment: @xiaowl No errors are on the browser console.
@vector I am able to get the parameter values from the previous page, I'm just wondering why my alert functions aren't being called in certain locatins. Maybe I'm calling my functions incorrectly? I even added a Test button:

`<input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:preloadDropdownBoxes();"/>`

And the test button isn't working either. I even threw in an alert in the button.

Comment: Hi, can you copy&paste the **generated** HTML source code somewhere, so we can know the whole HTML context.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yRy7n/

Comment: @ArunPJohny The dropdown box isn't being preselected to the 3rd index though?

Comment: @xiaowl Here is the full jsp code http://pastebin.com/nnwMeFeA

Comment: It is working at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yRy7n/1/ - previous one was not working because all the select boxes was not added.

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML from browser instead of the JSP. Use the View Source functionality of the browser to get the HTML

Comment: Also looks like many `select` boxes are missing like `futureTwoYear`, `future` etc where are they

Comment: @ArunPJohny Here is the HTML http://pastebin.com/dFPwAS9d

The other select boxes aren't necessary right now. I'm writing this for other possible pages. I'm just trying to isolate the problem. Not sure why my functions aren't being called even at the bottom. My `window.alert('document ready on bottom');` isn't being called because it's AFTER the `window.preloadDropdownBoxes();` and `document.getElementById('future').selectedIndex = 2;` it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here

1. A strayed `}` at line number 125 (Just above the `</head>` tag at the end of comments
2. The variable `futureTwoYear` is not defined. You may have to define `var futureTwoYear= '2014-2015';`

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Edit Calendar</title>

<link href="/SpringApp6/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/SpringApp6/js/tsds_new.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SpringApp6/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
                //this alert not working
                alert('alert1');

        function selectAll() {
                var cancelElements = new Array();
                cancelElements = document.getElementsByName("cancel");
                if (cancelElements[0].checked == true) {
                        for (i = 1; i < cancelElements.length; i++) {
                                if (cancelElements[i].disabled != true
                                                && cancelElements[i].checked != true) {
                                        cancelElements[i].checked = true;
                                }
                        }
                } else if(cancelElements[0].checked != true){
                        for (j = 1; j < cancelElements.length; j++) {                          
                                if (cancelElements[j].disabled != true
                                                && cancelElements[j].checked == true) {
                                        cancelElements[j].checked = false;
                                }
                        }
                }              
        }

        function passDetails(campus,timestamp, jobname) {
                var camp = document.getElementById(campus).innerText;
                var tstamp = document.getElementById(timestamp).innerText;
                var jname = document.getElementById(jobname).innerText;
                window.location.href = "scheduleLoad.jsp?campus="+camp+"&timestamp="
                                + tstamp + "&jobName=" + jname;
        }
        function checkSelectAll(){             
                var cancelElements = new Array();
                cancelElements = document.getElementsByName("cancel");
                var selectAll=true;            
                for (j = 1; j < cancelElements.length; j++) {                          
                                if (cancelElements[j].disabled != true
                                                && cancelElements[j].checked != true) {
                                                selectAll=false;
                                                break;
                                        }
                }
                if(selectAll==true){
                        cancelElements[0].checked=true;
                }else{
                        cancelElements[0].checked=false;
                }
        }

        /* Reset collection calendar search dropdown boxes */
        function resetSearch() {
                document.getElementById('sYear').selectedIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('collectionPeriod').selectedIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('submission').selectedIndex = 0;
        }

        //preselect dropdown based on URL parameter
        function preloadDropdownBoxes() {
                //preload function alert not calling
                alert('preload function called');
                //mapping vars to java variables
                var sYear = 'past';
                var collectionPeriod = 'FALL1';
                var submission = 'First';
                var availDate = '2013-01-30';
                var openDate = '2013-01-30';
                var closeDate = '2013-01-30';
                //these are time generated values based on calendar instance
                var pastTwoYear = '2010-2011';
                var pastYear = '2011-2012';
                var currentYear = '2012-2013';
                var futureYear = '2013-2014';
                var futureTwoYear = '2014-2015';
                //change selectedIndex values if dropdown in JSP has "pastTwoYear"
                if (sYear == pastTwoYear) {
                        document.getElementById('pastTwoYear').selectedIndex = 0;
                } else if (sYear == pastYear) {
                        document.getElementById('past').selectedIndex = 0;
                        alert(sYear + '0');
                } else if (sYear == currentYear) {
                        document.getElementById('current').selectedIndex = 1;
                        alert(sYear + '1');
                } else if (sYear == futureYear) {
                        document.getElementById('future').selectedIndex = 2;
                        alert(sYear + '2');
                } else if(sYear == futureTwoYear) {
                        document.getElementById('futureTwoYear').selectedIndex = 3;
                        alert(sYear + '3');
                }
        } //end preLoadDropdownBoxes()

        function test() {
                alert('yolo');
        }

//               alert(document.editCalendarForm1.sYear1.options.length);

//     // Get a reference to the drop-down
//     var myDropdownList = document.editCalendarForm1.sYear1;
//     int iLoop = 0;
//     alert(myDropdownList.options.length);
//     // Loop through all the items
//     for ( iLoop; iLoop< myDropdownList.options.length; iLoop++)
//     {
//      alert(myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value);

//       if (myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value == abc)
//       {
//         // Item is found. Set its selected property, and exit the loop
//         sYear1.options[iLoop].selected = true;
//         break;
//       }
//     }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- onload="javascript:openMail();" -->

<table class="maintable" align="center">
        <tbody>
                <!-- header -->

<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PEIMS</title>
<link href="/SpringApp6/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="logoplaceholder">
            <div id="logo"> <img src="images/tsdslogo.png" width="287" height="88" alt="tsds logo" /> </div>
            <!--  <div id="search"><input id="input" type="text"/><img src="images/Search.png" width="87" height="23"/>
                        </div>  -->

        </div>

        <div style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;
        </div>

        <div id="topbar">
                <div id="topbarcontent" style="margin-left:30px; border-right: solid 0px; margin-right:30px;">
                <b>Jonathan Washington</b>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;jwashington@washingtonheightsisd.com </div>
                <div id="topbarcontent"> My Messages (10)</div>                        
                <div id="topbarcontent"> Help Desk </div>
                                <div id="topbarcontent"> Exit </div>

              <div style="float: left; margin: 13px 5px 5px 5px;"><select>
        <option>Washington Heights ISD</option>
        <option>Austin ISD</option>
        <option>Dallas ISD</option>
        <option>Houston ISD</option>
</select></div>

<div id="topbarcontent"
        style="border-left: solid thin; border-right: none; border-color: #00A1DE"><img src="/SpringApp6/images/change.png" width="87" height="23" /></div>
</div>
        </div>


        </div>
</html>

                <!-- end header -->
                <!-- body -->
                <tr height="81%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <!-- left navigation -->
                        <td width="20%"><html>
<!-- <style>
.a {text-decoration:none}
</style> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        var context='/SpringApp6';
        document.write("<div id=\"leftNav\">");
        document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\"><a href=\"home.htm\" id=\"phome\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Home</a></div>");     
        document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\" ><a href=\"dataSubmissions.jsp\" id=\"dataSubmissions\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Data Submissions</a></div>");
        document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\" >Data Mart Loads</div>");
/*              document.write("<span id=\"listLoads\" style=\"display: none; padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\">");
 */             document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"scheduleLoad.htm\" id=\"scheduleLoad\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Manage Data Loads</a><br/></div>");
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\"><a href=\"scheduleMonitor.htm\" id=\"scheduleMonitor\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Monitor Data Loads</a></div>");
                /* document.write("</span>");  */      
                document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\" ><a href=\"collectionMonitor.htm\" id=\"collectionMonitor\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Collection Status Monitor</a></div>");
                document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\">Administration</div>");
                /* document.write("<span id=\"listAdminTasks\" style=\"display: none; padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\">"); */
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"collectionCalendar.htm\" id=\"collCalendar\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Collection Calendar</a><br/></div>");
                //document.write("<a href=\"viewCalendar.jsp\" id=\"viewCalendar\">View Calendar</a><br/>");
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"extnRequest.jsp\" id=\"extnReq\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Request Extension</a><br/></div>");
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"extnApproval.jsp\" id=\"extnApproval\" style=\"text-decoration:none\"> Approve Extensions</a><br/></div>");
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"configureNotifications.jsp\" id=\"configNotifications\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Configure Notifications</a></div>");
                /* document.write("</span></div>"); */         
        /*      document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\"><a href=\"#\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Data Access</a></div>"); */
                document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\">Data Access</div>");
                /* document.write("<span id=\"listDataTasks\" style=\"display: none; padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\">"); */
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"dataSearch.jsp\" id=\"dataSearch\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Data Search</a><br/></div>");
                //document.write("<a href=\"viewCalendar.jsp\" id=\"viewCalendar\">View Calendar</a><br/>");
                document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\" ><a href=\"rosterSearch.jsp\" id=\"rosterSearch\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Roster Search</a><br/></div>");          
                /* document.write("</span></div>"); */         
                //document.write("<div style=\"padding-bottom: 20px;\"><a href=\"dataSearch.jsp\" id=\"dataSearch\">Data Search</a></div>");
                //document.write("<div style=\"padding-bottom: 20px;\"><a href=\"rosterSearch.jsp\" id=\"rosterSearch\">Roster Search</a></div>");

                document.write("</div>");
                var loc=location.href; 

</script>
<!-- <div style="padding-bottom: 120px;"></div> -->
</html></td>
                        <!-- end left navigation -->
                        <!-- main content  -->
                        <td width="55%" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <div
                                style="font-family: sans-serif; padding-bottom: 15px; color: #0099CC;">
                        Administration >> Collection Calendar >> <b>Edit Collection Calendar</b></div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                        <h3>Edit Collection Calendar</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- BEGIN EDIT FORM -->
                        <form id="editCalendarForm1" action="/SpringApp6/editCalendar.htm?collKey=1&amp;sYear=past&amp;collectionPeriod=FALL1&amp;submission=First&amp;availDate=2013-01-30&amp;openDate=2013-01-30&amp;closeDate=2013-01-30" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="initLoad" value="rich1"/>

                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;

                        <table style="width: 100%; margin: auto; font: 100%; border: hidden;">
                                <tr
                                        style="height: 15px; border-bottom-color: transparent; border-bottom-width: 0;">
                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: hidden;"><b>School
                                        Year</b>:</td>
                                        <td style="border: hidden;">
                                                <select name="sYear1" id="sYear1" onchange="javascript:PreselectMyItem();">
                                                        <option value="past">2011-2012</option>
                                                        <option value="current">2012-2013</option>
                                                        <option value="future">2013-2014</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- COLLECTION PERIOD -->
                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: hidden;"><b>Collection</b>:</td>
                                        <td style="border: hidden;">
                                                <select name="collectionPeriod1" id="collectionPeriod1" >
                                                        <option value="FALL1" id="FALL1">Collection1(FALL1)</option>
                                                        <option value="FALL2" id="FALL2">Collection1(FALL2)</option>
                                                        <option value="working1" id="working1">Collection1(Working)</option>
                                                        <option value="MDYR1" id="MDYR1">Collection2(MDYR1)</option>
                                                        <option value="MDYR2" id="MDYR2">Collection2(MDYR2)</option>
                                                        <option value="working2" id="working2" >Collection2(Working)</option>
                                                        <option value="SUMR1" id="SUMR1">Collection3(SUMR1)</option>
                                                        <option value="SUMR2" id="SUMR2">Collection3(SUMR2)</option>
                                                        <option value="working3" id="working3">Collection3(Working)</option>
                                                        <option value="EXYR1" id="EXYR1">Collection4(EXYR1)</option>
                                                        <option value="EXYR2" id="EXYR2">Collection4(EXYR2)</option>
                                                        <option value="working4" id="working4">Collection4(Working)</option>
                                                        <option value="DASH1" id="DASH1">Collection5(DASH1)</option>
                                                        <option value="DASH2" id="DASH2">Collection5(DASH2)</option>
                                                        <option value="working5" id="working5">Collection5(Working)</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- SUBMISSION -->
                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: hidden;"><b>Submission</b>:</td>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="border: hidden;">
                                                <select name="submission1" id="submission1">
                                                        <option>First</option>
                                                        <option>Second</option>
                                                        <option>Working</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </td>

                                </tr>  

                                <!-- SELECT DATE -->
                                <tr style="height: 15px; border-bottom-color: transparent; border-bottom-width: 0;">
                                        <td style="border: hidden;" colspan="3"><b>Available Date:</b>
                                                <input name="availDate1" type="Text" id="availDate1" class="calText" size="25" value="01/30/2013"
                                                readonly="readonly" />&nbsp;<img src="/SpringApp6/images/cal.gif"
                                                width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"
                                                onclick="javascript:NewCal('availDate','MMddyyyy',false,12);"
                                                align="bottom">
                                        </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr style="height: 15px; border-bottom-color: transparent; border-bottom-width: 0;">
                                        <td style="border: hidden;" colspan="3"><b>Open Date:</b>
                                                <input name="openDate1" type="Text" id="openDate1" class="calText" size="25" value="01/30/2013"
                                                readonly="readonly" />&nbsp;<img src="/SpringApp6/images/cal.gif"
                                                width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"
                                                onclick="javascript:NewCal('openDate','MMddyyyy',false,12);"
                                                align="bottom">
                                        </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr style="height: 15px; border-bottom-color: transparent; border-bottom-width: 0;">
                                        <td style="border: hidden;" colspan="3"><b>Close Date:</b>
                                                <input name="closeDate1" type="Text" id="closeDate1" class="calText" size="25" value="01/30/2013"
                                                readonly="readonly" />&nbsp;<img src="/SpringApp6/images/cal.gif"
                                                width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"
                                                onclick="javascript:NewCal('closeDate','MMddyyyy',false,12);"
                                                align="bottom">
                                                <br><br>
                                                <!-- <input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="javascript:window.close()"> -->
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Collection Edits"/> &nbsp;
                        <input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:alert('hey');"/>
                        <!-- END EDIT -->
                        <!-- <table class="gridtable" style="width: 100%">
                        </table> -->
                        </form>
                        <!-- <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr style="height: 20px;"></tr>
                        </table> -->
                        </td>
                        <!--end mainContent-->
                </tr>
                <!-- footer -->

                <!-- footer -->
        </tbody>
</table>
        <div id="copyright" align="center">

         <div id="copyright">

        </div>
    <script>
//     these two alert calls
    alert('footer');
    alert('footer next');
//     these functions aren't
        window.preloadDropdownBoxes();
        document.getElementById('future').selectedIndex = 2;
        window.alert('document ready on bottom');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I didn't realize that Eclipse IDE didn't check for correct locations of parentheses. It's all working now!

Comment: I was looking in the wrong location then. Thanks, I'll check in the browser console from here on.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an html please refer below. its working in chrome and IE. All alerts are working fine.

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    alert('alert1');
    window.preloadDropdownBoxes();

function preloadDropdownBoxes() {
    //preload function alert not calling
    alert('preload function called');
    //mapping vars to java variables
    var sYear = '<%=sYear%>';
    var collectionPeriod = '<%=collectionPeriod%>';
    var submission = '<%=submission%>';
    var availDate = '<%=availDate%>';
    var openDate = '<%=openDate%>';
    var closeDate = '<%=closeDate%>';
    //these are time generated values based on calendar instance
    var pastTwoYear = '<%=pastTwoYear%>';
    var pastYear = '<%=pastYear%>';
    var currentYear = '<%=currentYear%>';
    var futureYear = '<%=futureYear%>';
    //change selectedIndex values if dropdown in JSP has "pastTwoYear"
    if (sYear == pastTwoYear) {
        document.getElementById('pastTwoYear').selectedIndex = 0;
    } else if (sYear == pastYear) {
        document.getElementById('past').selectedIndex = 0;
        alert(sYear + '0');
    } else if (sYear == currentYear) {
        document.getElementById('current').selectedIndex = 1;
        alert(sYear + '1');
    } else if (sYear == futureYear) {
        document.getElementById('future').selectedIndex = 2;
        alert(sYear + '2');
    } else if(sYear == futureTwoYear) {
        document.getElementById('futureTwoYear').selectedIndex = 3;
        alert(sYear + '3');
    }
} 


function preselectMyItem(value)
{

    alert("Selected value is == "+value);

}

</script>


</head>
<body>


<table>

<tr>

<form action="#" method="GET">
<td>select year</td>
<td><select name="sYear1" id="sYear1" onchange="javascript:preselectMyItem(this.value);">
                        <option value="past">past</option>
                        <option value="current">current</option>
                        <option value="future">future</option>
                    </select>
</td>


</form>

</tr>

</table>



</body>

</html>
```

Make sure there is no error in jsp page at runtime.

Comment: Let me know if you are looking for other than this solution. We can solve the problem with little effort. don't worry friend.

Comment: You can modify option values with dynamic value later once page started working as expected.

Comment: This is another great way to tackle this. Thank you for your input.